# Drupal Commerce & cURL

Tags: curl, drupal-commerce

I'm trying to install Drupal Commerce kickstarter on Windows 10.

I forgot WAMP and use EasyPHP :p

Now I've got a problem with cURL...

I've download the library, tried to ping google with a `curl http://www.google.fr` and this work, I get the header !

But when I try to install Drupal Commerce again, it says that curl is not found !?

Answer (score 0):

Copy php_curl.dll from EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-binaries\php\ext

and libssh2.dll, ssleay32.dll, libeay32.dll from EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-binaries\php

Move them to Windows\system32 folder

Copy libssh2.dll

Go to

EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-binaries\httpserver\apache\bin

Go to EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-binaries\php

Open php.ini and enable curl (remove ; before "extension=php_curl.dll")

this should do it